# How to limit crawl on specific site collection?

Tags: crawl-rules

Need some guidance on how to limit crawl. I have a site collection that I will create it's content source. However, I want to make sure this site collection is not being crawled by the main content source. How to do that or how to limit crawl?

Comment: Please confirm: Central Admin > Search Service App > Crawl Rules > "New Crawl Rule" > Put URL and select "Exclude".

Comment: This is correct. You can also exclude single lists, libraries - in the Library (or list) settings - Advanced Settings - Allow items from this list to appear in search results? (Yes/No)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be correct.  If you wanted to create a separate content source and exclude it from the All Sites scope, you'd put an exclusion rule in place.